# Create a window act like system default menu?

Tags: winapi, user-interface

I created a window in a main window. When the new window shows, the main window lose its focus and deactivate.

So the frame of the main window is not activated, as following picture shown:
[image]

while the activated main window should look like this:
[image]

The problem is I need to keep the main window activated while I create and show the new window, which resemble system menu window.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int HandledWidget::showPopup()
{
    int nRet(-1);

    show(SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE);

    BOOL bMenuDestroyed(FALSE);
    BOOL bMsgQuit(FALSE);
    HWND m_hWndOwner = GetWindow(m_hWnd, GW_OWNER);
    assert(GetForegroundWindow() == m_hWndOwner);

    while(TRUE)
    {
        if(GetProp(m_hWnd, MENU_EXIT_NOTIFY) != 0)
        {
            nRet = (int)GetProp(m_hWnd, MENU_EXIT_COMMAND_ID);
            break;
        }

        if(GetActiveWindow() != m_hWndOwner)
        {
            break;
        }

        m_bIsPopingUp = true;

        MSG msg = {0};
        if(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            if(msg.message == WM_KEYDOWN
                || msg.message == WM_SYSKEYDOWN
                || msg.message == WM_KEYUP
                || msg.message == WM_SYSKEYUP
                || msg.message == WM_CHAR
                || msg.message == WM_IME_CHAR
                || msg.message == WM_MOUSEWHEEL
                )
            {
                //transfer the message to menu window
                msg.hwnd = m_hWnd;
            }
            else if(msg.message == WM_LBUTTONDOWN
                || msg.message == WM_RBUTTONDOWN
                || msg.message == WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN
                || msg.message == WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN)
            {
                //click on other window
                if(msg.hwnd != m_hWnd)
                {
                    m_bIsPopingUp = false;
                    DestroyWindow(m_hWnd);
                    bMenuDestroyed = TRUE;
                }
            }
            else if(msg.message == WM_QUIT)
            {
                bMsgQuit = TRUE;
            }

            TranslateMessage (&msg);
            DispatchMessageW (&msg);
        }
        else
        {
            MsgWaitForMultipleObjects (0, 0, 0, 10, QS_ALLINPUT);
        }

        if(bMenuDestroyed) break;

        if(bMsgQuit)
        {
            PostQuitMessage(msg.wParam);
            break;
        }
    }

    m_bIsPopingUp = false;

    if(!bMenuDestroyed) DestroyWindow(m_hWnd);

    return nRet;
}

bool HandledWidget::exitPopup(int nCommandId)
{
    BOOL bRet = SetProp(m_hWnd, MENU_EXIT_NOTIFY, (HANDLE)1);
    SetProp(m_hWnd, MENU_EXIT_COMMAND_ID, (HANDLE)nCommandId);
    return bRet;
}
```

and handle wm_mouseactivate:

```
LRESULT ComboxList::onMouseActivate( WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, bool &bHandled )
{
    bHandled = true;
    return MA_NOACTIVATE;
}
```

remember do not activate the new window using SetFocus/SetWindowPos(SW_SHOWWINDOW)/ShowWindow(SW_SHOW)/SetActivate/SetForegroundWindow etc.

Then you get a non-activate window just like the system menu.

reference:http://www.cppblog.com/weiym/archive/2013/04/07/199189.html

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like SW_SHOWNA/SWP_NOACTIVATE for new window ?

Comment: was inattentive :-(. Read "FakeMenu" by R.Chen (in SDK)

Comment: kero, thx for your reply, I find fakemenu really helps, but could you expand your answer with more details.